# Actualizar Label dentro de un bucle

Tags: javafx

No consigo que se actualice en pantalla un simple bucle for. El programa arranca y cuando llega al final del bucle muestra el último valor. Se que tiene que ver con concurrencia y los hilos pero no he sabido solucionarlo.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
@FXML
private Button id_boton1;
@FXML
private Label id_texto1;


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    id_boton1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            hacerTarea();
        }
    });
}

private void hacerTarea() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        try {
            sleep(10);
            id_texto1.setText("N: " + i);
            System.out.println(i);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Has probado a usar el método append en vez de setText?, ya que lo que hace este ultimo es borrar lo que habia y poner lo que le indicas, append mantiene lo que habia y añade al final lo que indiques

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema se resume en que el `TextField` se actualiza muy rapido por lo que no notas la diferencia(imaginate a una velocidad de milisegundos) y solo ves el resultado final cuando acaba.

Una solucion seria crear un hilo paralelo con un `sleep` que vaya actualizando el `TextField`

Te dejo un pequño ejemplo de como hacer un hilo:

```
   Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        try{
            id_texto1.setText("N: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Vamos a actualizar el valor cada segundo
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});

thread.start();
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, aunque tu respuesta aclara el problema, sería un plus si agregas un pequeño ejemplo de lo que propones, de esa forma tu contribución será mejor recibida. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

tu código me ha servido aunque tal cual está da error pero encontré como corregirlo. Tuve que meter dentro de un Platform.runLater el setText del Label porque me daba un error de java.lang.IllegalStateException por un conflicto de hilos al modificar la UI. Con esta modificación ahora sí que funciona. Es complicada esta forma de programar en Java. Aparte del tema de los hilos, dentro del Platform.runLater las variables han de ser finales con lo que se ha usar una variable que haga de puente para poder imprimir "un simple contador" con un bucle for. Gracias Victor Manuel

```
 Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {

        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
            try{
                final int contador = i;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        id_texto1.setText("N: " + contador);
                    }
                });

                Thread.sleep(1000); // Vamos a actualizar el valor cada segundo
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
```

Comment: Es un placer haberte podido ayudar, si al final la respuesta te ha sido util marca la pregunta como [aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: ya lo hice @VictorManuel Si crees que mi pregunta es útil también puedes puntuarla. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

otra solución que he investigado es usando Task. La comparto porque seguro puede ser de interés para mas gente:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() {
            //final int max = 1000000;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                final int contador = i;
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        id_texto1.setText("N: " + contador);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000); // Vamos a actualizar el valor cada segundo
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    new Thread(task).start();
```